# delay conflict when multiple click methods fire other delay methods while the current delay hasn't ended yet

Tags: jquery

When i fire one of the click methods , delay() works fine if i don't interrupt it with another click.
So i click wait till the delay ends, click another element wait again and everything works fine.
But if i click an element and interrupt the current delay than , delay messes up .

```
//Newsfeed It Clicked
$("[movie_id='"+movie_id+"'] .newsfeed_it").click(function(){
    $("#header .message").css({"display":"block"}).html("<img src='images/loader.gif'/>");
    $.post("ajax/movie_load.php", {load_type:3, movie_id:movie_id, do_it:1},function(loadtext){
        $("#header .message").text(loadtext).delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
    });
    return false;
});
//Favorite It Clicked
$("[movie_id='"+movie_id+"'] .favorite_it").click(function(){
    $("#header .message").css({"display":"block"}).html("<img src='images/loader.gif'/>");
    $.post("ajax/movie_load.php", {load_type:3, movie_id:movie_id, do_it:2},function(loadtext){
        $("#header .message").text(loadtext).delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
    });
    return false;
});
//Later It Clicked
$("[movie_id='"+movie_id+"'] .later_it").click(function(){
    $("#header .message").css({"display":"block"}).html("<img src='images/loader.gif'/>");
    $.post("ajax/movie_load.php", {load_type:3, movie_id:movie_id, do_it:3},function(loadtext){
        $("#header .message").text(loadtext).delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Take a look at `stop()`: http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: What do you want to be the behavior when you click again before the animation is done?

Comment: show the text returned by the ajax call and i want the text to stay again for 3 seconds on the screen and then to be disappeared

Comment: Im using : $("#header .message").stop(true);
when each click method is fired and everything is working just fine :)